# ICS (Samsung Nexus) Calendar Default Event Duration

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, calendar, samsung-galaxy-nexus

Been trying to change the default duration while creating an event on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus stock calendar. It's defaulted to be 1 hour but I'd like to change to 30 minutes like I can on Google Calendar on Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look like it has one.